# Why do annihilation photons always have perpendicular polarization?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-field-theory, optics, photons

It seems to be general knowledge that the two photons coming from $e^+ e^-$-Annihilation via positronium are perpendicular polarized. Why is that ?

My idea is that if they are not perpendicular polarized, one axis is special and thus the isotropy is sort of broken (?)

Comment: Because $k\cdot \epsilon=0$.

Comment: See https://sites.fas.harvard.edu/~phys191r/References/b3/Harpen2004.pdf in the Appendix.

Comment: Please give a reference. What is your question?